# how to use hyperlink in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml-formatting

Here is the code:

```
        var loc = $(this).find('loc').text();
        var locSearch = loc.search(reg);

        if(descSearch > -1){
        $('#output').append('Found <i>'+searchFor+'<\/i> in loc: '+loc.replace(reg, '<b>'+searchFor+'</b>')+'<br \/>');
    }
```

and here is xml format:

```
    <entry>
    <title>Test 2 title </title>
    <description>Description for Test 2</description>
    <loc><a href="http://www.test2.com/">Test2 Text</a></loc>
    </entry>
```

But the result is just `Test2 Text` It's not linkable, I want that the result will be appeared with linkable text, I mean, When we click on `Test2 Text` then `http://www.test2.com/` will open.

For your information, this format is function parseXML for webpage custom search.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
string.link(url)
```

Example:

```
<script>

var str = "Free Web Building Tutorials!";
document.write(str.link("http://www.w3schools.com"));

</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, this method is not working into my code. pls check my code again